# Is there a way to be notified when a wiki page changes on a Google Code hosted site?

Tags: hosting, wiki, google-code

Is there a way to be automatically notified (via email) when a wiki page changes on a Google Code hosted site?

Answer (score 3):

I'll use http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/FAQ as an example. The page has an RSS feed of edits, http://code.google.com/feeds/p/mutagen/svnchanges/basic?path=/wiki/FAQ.wiki.

If you wish to know when any page in the wiki is edited, then the wiki index page and it's associated RSS feed (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/w/list and http://code.google.com/feeds/p/mutagen/svnchanges/basic?path=/wiki/) should do the job.

Use [IFTTT feeds](https://ifttt.com/feed) or a more dedicated service such as [Blogtrottr](http://blogtrottr.com/). Enter the RSS feed URL and your email address, then off you go.

EDIT: In fact Blogtrottr works with the URL of the wiki page, no need to work out the RSS URL. IFTTT might also.

Comment: Thanks. I've used these feeds before, but I was hoping for a more non-developer friendly solution. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've found a simpler way of doing things.

1. Go to: https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
2. Click on the checkbox against "Whenever comments are added to a wiki page by another user, send me an email"
3. Star the wiki pages you want to be notified about.